# Link to the last published version on a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing, wiki, version-history

Is it possible to have a link on a page that always points to the last published (or highest major version)?

> i.e. we don't want to have to change the page when that published version changes, so a hard link won't work for us.

The background in case there's a simpler way:

We have a Wiki site containing process documentation, and the rules are you should only follow the approved (i.e. `published version`).

Unfortunately the parts of the process can be `reviewed/approved` by the vast majority of the audience, so they see the '`Checked in and viewable by authorized users`.' yellow bar.

Note we are using SharePoint Online, with no access to the Designer client.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you're looking for, but it's the best solution (workaround?) I have. I would definitely like to see a simpler solution if one exists.

In order to get editing permissions to our wiki site, our users must:

- confirm understanding that as editors, SharePoint will now present them with the unpublished versions of pages by default, and that the key indicator of this is the presence of the yellow banner,

  and
- agree to use the following procedure anytime they see the yellow bar on any page they access for use as a reference (obviously, there's no need to do so if they're accessing the page to edit it):

  - Click **PAGE** in the SharePoint ribbon
  - Click **Page History** in the PAGE ribbon
  - Click **Version History** in the Page History toolbar
  - Locate the "current published major version" in the list
  - Click on the timestamp to view that version

While this 4-click procedure is far from ideal, it works ok for us because our audience is a single team in a corporate environment. If the site's audience had less of an incentive to voluntarily comply with this procedure, I imagine we'd see a very low percentage of users following this procedure. And there's no easy way to identify someone who *doesn't* follow it, unless there's a draft that's significantly different from the published version *and* that person has occasion to refer to that particular process page.